# DDD entities to multi-task a business process?

Tags: domain-driven-design, business-process-management

I have a rather large aggregate root entity called Alert.  When an Alert is created, several complex things occur, so they are captured in a business process model and executed in the BPM Engine (e.g., the "Handle Alert" process).  There are various sets of data about the alert that can be independently add/updated by multiple people all working to resolve the alert at the same time (e.g. parallel User Tasks in a BPMN process).

This data means nothing to the business without the Alert and it cannot exist without the Alert.

However, because this additional data is added as the Alert moves through the business process, it feels like separate "entities".  This would prevent version errors on the single Alert aggregate root too as multiple people save their work to the business process.

Question:
Even though these dependent value objects really mean nothing without the Alert, and do not stand on their own, should I make them entities based on business process model's flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. In my experience, transactional analysis is a better design counsellor than any kind of "X cannot exist without Y" rule. If there's a lot of contention at stake, definitely try to identify and extract subparts of an aggregate that are more frequently accessed or independently accessed, and make them aggregates in their own right to ease the transactional pressure on the main object.